# Prove/disprove - A function that is Darboux-integrable with the following conditions exists.

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove/disprove that a function which is Darboux-integrable on [0,2] and meets the following conditions exists:

- $\int_0^1 f(x)dx < 1$
- $\int_0^2 f(x)dx > 2$
- for every $t \in [1,2] $, $\int_0^t f(x)dx \neq t$

I tried checking the antiderivative and using the intermediate value theorem in order to check what happens with the third condition. However, I don't know how to answer this properly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x) dx - t$; the third condition is now that this has no zeros on $[1,2]$. So if IVT can be used for $F$ on $[1,2]$ then the claim can be disproved.

If this doesn't work out then you might consider trying to prove the claim instead.

(By the way this "tilting" trick is pretty common in 1D analysis, for example it gives a quick proof of the mean value theorem from Rolle's theorem.)

Comment: Thanks. Shifting did the trick. The proof of mean value theorem is very elegant, didn't think of implying the same method here.